# To unlock new crops do I need to ship raw crops or just grow them?

Tags: harvest-moon-3d-a-new-beginning

I heard to unlock crops in A New Beginning you need to grow lots of "base" crops and ship them to unlock the next set. However I've been cooking most of my crops before I ship them for now, since it helps level my cooking and I get slightly more money.

Do I need to ship crops or just grow them to unlock new crops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the information found in http://fogu.com/hm11/farm/list-of-crops.php

In most cases, you can either wait till Hana's General Store sell it to you or you can win them in different festivals.

The only case where you have to ship a number of crops would be to unlock certain town restoration plans. More information for that can be found here:

http://fogu.com/hm11/basics/dunhill-plans.php

Comment: Must have been mistaken or hearing about a different game. That's a relief either way though